# Inserting Div element into TinyMCE in the same line with other text inside

Tags: html, tinymce, execcommand

I'm trying to insert a div element inside the tinyMCE editor, but each time I insert one it's inserted in a separate line!
what I want is to insert the div inline with the text already existing!
Can anyone help?

P.S: text is included directly in the editor's body (I've eliminated p elements)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Tinymce needs those root elements in order to be able to style lines of text.
There are several means to get rid of unwanted tags onSubmit, but that depends on the use case.

Comment: maybe I wasn't clear explaining my question! I need to insert the div with the tags! but I need it to be inline with the text existing! is that possible?

Comment: can you show me an exact example htlm code of what you want? (there might be a way)

Comment: $('.droppable').droppable({
                accept: '.draggable',
                drop: function (ev, ui) {
                    
                        var textVal = $(ui.draggable[0]).clone();
                        textVal[0].innerHTML = "{" + textVal[0].innerHTML + "}";
                        tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, textVal[0].outerHTML);
                }
            });

As you can see I'm trying to insert the whole dropped div to include it's class!
Is that possible?

Comment: @Thariama when i insert a div element such as 
                                     tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, `<div class="tme-vimeo-wrapper"><iframe src=${returnedVideoUrl} width="100%" height="auto" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe></div>`) 

the next lines are always divs and no longer p tags, any idea why this is?

Comment: yes, because you probably insert ENTER inside a div which will create a new element of that kind in the editor. what element dou you have set as blook_root?